# How to extends dynamic template in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, extends

i need to extends different base template in twig. this is possible? in my code i use dinamically render template with a controller like this

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:menuManager')) }}
```

in that controller i use one action to choose the right template to render in my page, and this work fine. But in this case is different: i what change my base default (so i presume to extends it, right?) but i don't know how do this. Something like this?

```
{{ extends(controller('AppBundle:Default:baseManager')) }}
```

But this code don't work. Is possible? There is a different way? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `{{ extends template_from_string(controller('AppBundle:Default:baseManager')) }}`? Reference: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/template_from_string.html

Comment: i tried and i presume that tempalte_from_string dont work with extends, but only include

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the conditions for choosing the template base but you can use a **twig extension**. I use that in one project :

```
{% extends app.request.host | switchBaseTemplate %}
```

In this example, I use the host for the condition.
You can then write a twig extension easily, as explained here : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Have good dev.